# Can I do something with my partitions so I can install Windows alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, partitioning

I had Windows and installed Ubuntu alongside. Somehow GRUB wouldn't recognize Windows, so I erased the Windows partition and attempted to reinstall it, however I got error messages like "the partition is not windows-compatible". My partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` - Ubuntu
- `/dev/sda5` - Ubuntu swap
- `/dev/sda6` - A previously installed Ubuntu version-not using it anymore
- `/dev/sda7` - only data, no OS

I could potentially delete all partitions if needed **except** my data partition (sda7).

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to resize the Ubuntu partition, and then create a new partition with the NTFS file system. Then install windows from the CD to that partition (it will automatically pick that up as the partition to install to). You may need create an Ubuntu liveCD, and use it to reinstall grub, as windows will have replaced grub with its bootloader. (I can provide a link on how to do this if necessary). TL;DR make sure there is an NTFS partition somewhere on the disk.

Comment: That's what I did, I should have mentioned it explicitly. I think it has something to do with windows bootloader and wanting to be the first partition on a disk?

Comment: Could be. Sorry I didn't realise you'd already done that, I couldn't see an NTFS partition in the image. I take it you deleted it when it didn't work?

Comment: Yeah that's right

Comment: Windows does not have to be the first partition although it usually is. But it does have to be a primary partition formatted NTFS with the boot flag. You can install a second version of Windows to a logical partition but the second version puts all its boot files in the first install that is a primary partition. Or you can create just a small Boot partition that is primary NTFS with the boot flag.